# Laravel 5.4 transaction and one-many relation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I just started laravel but I'm stuck to this point and I don't find a way to do it

Basically I insert an article with a category.

With select2, I select an existing category or I create a new one.

My article model :

```
public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

My categories model :

```
public function articles(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
}
```

My article migration :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->longText('content')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

My category migration :

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nom')->unique();
    });

    Schema::table('articles', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
    });
```

And finally my controller function to store article (I want to use transaction) :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'numero' => 'required',
        'category' => 'required',
        'title' => 'required'
    ]);
    $article = new Article();
    DB::transaction(function() use ($request) {
       $category = Category::firstOrCreate(['nom' => $request->input('category')]);
       $article->title = $request->input('title');
       $article->save();
    });
    return response()->json([
        'title' => $article->title
    ]);
}
```

So I know I don't save category id into article db but my category doesn't even insert, on my debug bar I've got this :

> Begin Transaction
>   select * from `batiments` where (`nom` = 'HI') limit 1
>   Rollback Transaction

And my post page give me this error :

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicata du champ '' pour la clef 'batiments_nom_unique' (SQL: insert into `batiments` () values ())

Someone knpw how to insert or select if exist category and insert is id into article table ?

Thank

Comment: `articles` table should contains `category_id` field and relation within migration file should be in article migration not in category migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->index();`

You set this field as index, just remove index(). Identity field must have only unique records, but your `category_id` may have same value many times.

Comment: Oooooh right ! Thanks !
The rest of the code is the right way to do it ?

Comment: Yes, there's no another issues

Answer (score 0):

code:

```
$table->integer('categorie_id')->unsigned(); 

$table->foreign('categorie_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
```

Laravel provides support for creating foreign key constraints, which are used to force referential integrity at the database level. For example, let's define a categorie_id column on the articles table that references the id column on a categories table
 [laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#foreign-key-constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

Comment: please add explanation

Comment: Laravel  provides support for creating foreign key constraints, which are used to force referential integrity at the database level. For example, let's define a categorie_id column on the  articles table that references the id column on a categories table:   https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Comment: add this in your answer, not in comment

Comment: My way to do it isn't right ? I find this on a article :/